# install sass on windows getting error

Tags: ruby, sass, window

I have installed Ruby on windows and now trying to install sass but it is showing following error. Tried every possible solution but of no use

```
C:\Ruby25>ruby -v
ruby 2.5.0p0 (2017-12-25 revision 61468) [i386-mingw32]

C:\Ruby25>gem -v
2.6.8

C:\Ruby25>gem install sass
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (ArgumentError)
    wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)
```